# Directive and Mixins in nativescript Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

i'm trying to add nativescript module into vue-nativescript.

the directive that i need:

nativescript-ng-shadow.

how to import add to vue?

i try these way:

```
 Vue.registerElement('shadow', () => require('nativescript-ng-shadow').NgShadowModule)
```

and

```
new Vue({
directives: {
    shadow: () => require('nativescript-ng-shadow').NgShadowModule
},
render: h => h('frame', [h(HelloWorld)])

}).$start();
```

but none is working !!!!

Comment: As this link suggests, I think the above plugin can be used only with Angular. https://plugins.nativescript.rocks/plugin/nativescript-ng-shadow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an Angular specific module, not for Vue. If you like to utilise the shadow feature form the plugin, you will have to directly access their [JS apis](https://github.com/Especializa/nativescript-ng-shadow/blob/master/src/common/shadow.ts) or build an Vue directive within your project using same [plugin apis](https://github.com/Especializa/nativescript-ng-shadow/blob/master/src/angular/ng-shadow.directive.ts).